# Does the existence of a Algebraic Riccati Equation implies the existence of an functional minimization?

Tags: optimization, control-theory, dynamic-programming, optimal-control, linear-control

Let $\forall k\ge 0. V_k(x)$ be the value function related to the recursive optimization problem

$ J(x_0) = \underset{u}{\inf} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} x_k^T Q x_k + u_k^T R u_k + x_{N}^T P_N x_N \\ s.t. x_{k+1} = A x_k + B u_k $

then it is possible to prove that

$V_k(x) = \inf_u x^T Q x + u^T R u + V_{k+1}(A x + B u) = x^T P_k x$

where

$ P_k = A^T P_{k+1} A + Q - A^T P_{k+1} B (R + B^T P_{k+1} B)^{-1} B^T P_{k+1} A $

This last equation is the Discrete Algebraic Riccati Equation (DARE). 
It can be proved that an generalized version of the DARE above is an unique solution for any quadratic dynamic programming functional with linear dynamics such as J(x_0). Therefore the existence of $ J(x_0) $ implies the existence of the DARE, however does the opposite hold?

**Does the existence of a DARE implies the existence of a quadratic optimization with linear dynamics?**

Comment: Massera  What do you mean by existence of $J(x_0)$? Do you mean....." existence of quadratic cost implies that $P$ satisfy a DARE? Then the opposite of that statement would be "if $P$ satifies a DARE, does it mean that the cost is quadratic?"

Answer (score 0):

I write this as continuation to my comment, at the end (BOLD part of your question), are you concerned about the existence of a linear dynamics? That's actually the problem statement right? We start with a linear dynamics to derive the rest. Or am do I miss to follow your question? Anyway, for any given $A$, $B$, $Q$, and $R$, the solution $P$ of the DARE is unique solution. Hence if you are asking if given $P$, $B$, $Q$, and $R$, then  does it holds only for $A$? The answer should be YES as the equation is an equality.